# What's wrong with my jquery syntax and formating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What's wrong with this code? Probably a lot cus I'm new to jquery. I'm trying to fadeIn the page then fade the background to a different one the fade up and in the nav and set it up so the links will fade the page out and bring in the new page. The code I have now isn't quite working and I think some syntax and formatting is the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').fadeIn(1500);
});

$('#background').addClass('background');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#background').addClass('background-blured');
}, 1500);

$("h1").delay(2000).animate({
    top: -50,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 700, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});


$('.link').click(function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    newLocation = this.href;

    $('body').fadeOut(500, newpage);

});

function newpage() {

    window.location = newLocation;

}

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Properly indenting the code is the first step to spotting problems.

Comment: most of your code is outside *`document.ready`*. Learn to use proper indenting so you can see code wrapping

Comment: Syntax errors do trigger specific error messages in the JavaScript console. Is that the case?

Comment: Having indented your code appropriately, is it clearer what @charlietfl (and I) were saying?

Comment: I'm trying but I'm not complete 100% sure how to properly indent the code.

Comment: Every time you open a block, the contents of the block should be indented by 2 or 4 spaces, or a tab. The closing of the block should be at the same level as the opening of the block. The indentation in your question has been corrected, and as such you can clearly see that you closed your document ready callback too soon.

Comment: put `$('body').hide()` in the very first of your script (not inside `document.ready`, even before of it), and make sure the script is loaded just after the `body` is loaded

Comment: Don't put $('body').hide() in your script. just use "body { display: none; }" in your css to hide the body. If the script runs before the body element is loaded to the DOM then it will have no effect. If it doesn't run until after the Body is displayed it will flash on the screen. just using the css stylesheet is easier and less error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(document).ready triggers as soon as the DOM is fully loaded. Any javascript outside of the $(document).ready block is run while the browser is still loading the page. so if your $('#background') element is not yet loaded to the DOM jQuery cannot add the 'background' class to it. And more than likely only some of your $('.link') elements will have the click event listener added since they weren't yet loaded when the javascript ran. That's why you should embed such things inside the $(document).ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').fadeIn(1500);

    $('#background').addClass('background');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#background').addClass('background-blured');
    }, 1500);

    $("h1").delay(2000).animate({
        top: -50,
        opacity: 1,
    }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

    $('.link').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body').fadeOut(500, newpage);
    });
});

function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
}
```

Notice with proper indentation you can easily see what is inside the $(document).ready function. Also notice you don't put standard functions like your newpage() function inside the $(document).ready.